# Applying (with as few loops as possible) a function to given elements/voxels (x,y,z) taken from subfields of multiple structs (nifti's) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, imaging, nifti

I have a dataset of n nifti (.nii) images. Ideally, I'd like to be able to get the value of the same voxel/element from each image, and apply a function to the n data points. I'd like to do this for each voxel/element across the whole image, so that I can reconvert the result back into .nii format.

I've used the [Tools for NIfTI and ANALYZE image toolbox](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image) to load my images:

```
data(1)=load_nii('C:\file1.nii');
data(2)=load_nii('C:\file2.nii');
...
data(n)=load_nii('C:\filen.nii');
```

From which I obtain a struct object with each sub-field containing one loaded nifti. Each of these has a subfield 'img' corresponding to the image data I want to work on. The problem comes from trying to select a given xyz within each img field of data(1) to data(n). As I discovered, it isn't possible to select in this way:

```
data(:).img(x,y,z)
```

or

```
data(1:n).img(x,y,z)
```

because matlab doesn't support it. The contents of the first brackets have to be scalar for the call to work. The solution from googling around seems to be a loop that creates a temporary variable:

```
for z = 1:nz
    for x = 1:nx
        for y = 1:ny
            for i=1:n;
                points(i)=data(i).img(x,y,z);
            end
            [p1(x,y,z,:),~,p2(x,y,z)] = fit_data(a,points,b);
        end
end
end
```

which works, but takes too long (several days) for a single set of images given the size of nx, ny, nz (several hundred each).

I've been looking for a solution to speed up the code, which I believe depends on removing those loops by vectorisation, preselecting the img fields (via getfield ?)and concatenating them, and applying something like arrayfun/cellfun/structfun, but i'm frankly a bit lost on how to do it. I can only think of ways to pre-select which themselves require loops, which seems to defeat the purpose of the exercise (though a solution with fewer loops, or fewer nested loops at least, might do it), or fun into the same problem that calls like  data(:).img(x,y,z) dont work. googling around again is throwing up ways to select and concatenate fields within a struct, or a given field across multiple structs. But I can't find anything for my problem: select an element from a non-scalar sub-field in a sub-struct of a struct object (with the minimum of loops). Finally I need the output to be in the form of a matrix that the toolbox above can turn back into a nifti.

Any and all suggestions, clues, hints and help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate images as a 4D array and use linear indexes to speed up calculations:

```
img = cat(4,data.img);
p1 = zeros(nx,ny,nz,n);
p2 = zeros(nx,ny,nz);
sz = ny*nx*nz;
for k = 1 : sz 
    points = img(k:sz:end);
    [p1(k:sz:end),~,p2(k)] = fit_data(a,points,b);
end
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Currently my loop-heavy script is running, and should be nearly done, so I will giving your idea a try when that's finished. To clarify, my particular issue is that the data struct has n structs nested within it (data(1), data(2)...data(n)). The .img field is within those. My fit function needs to work on a given element across the .img fields (element x,y,z of data(1).img, data(2).img...data(n).img). If I'm understanding your code right, its applying the fit function to each element of a single data(n).img field from a single nifti?

Comment: Sorry for late reply . No, It is identical to your code it work across the img files.

Comment: Just wanted to apologize for the delay in replying. I integrated your suggestion and the script appears to be working, but hasn't finished yet (3days so far). Looks like I will have to be patient regardless of the implementation given the size of the data. I will feedback when the code completes.